# Using try_emplace with a shared_ptr

Tags: c++

So I have a `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<T>>` and I'd like to use `try_emplace` to add/reference elements. Previously, it was simply a `std::unordered_map<std::string, T>` and `T` has a constructor which just takes a `std::string`, so I was using `myMap.try_emplace(myString, myString).first->second` to reference the `T` and create it if necessary.

However, if I simply change it to `myMap.try_emplace(myString, std::make_shared<T>(myString)).first->second`, it, of course, constructs the `T` every time.

What's the most idiomatic way to get around this? To clarify, I'd like to construct the object on the heap with a shared pointer and insert the shared pointer into the unordered map if and only if there is not already a matching element in the map.

Comment: Do you really need `std::shared_ptr<T>` as the value type?

Comment: @NathanOliver Great question. I don't know. I do want the value to potentially exist beyond removing it from the unordered_map, though, so I think the answer is "yes"

Comment: This is why I would personally prefer `std::shared_ptr` to have a creating constructor, rather than have `std::make_shared`. This would solve your problem nicely and some other issues as well. But alas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `operator[]` instead:

```
auto &ptr = map[ key ];
if( !ptr ) ptr = std::make_shared<T>( myString );
```

Note: this solution came with assumption that you do not want to keep default constructed `std::shared_ptr` in the map. If that is the case, then you would need to use little more verbose code with `try_emplace`:

```
auto p = map.try_emplace( key, nullptr );
if( p.second ) p.first->second = std::make_shared<T>( myString );
else {
    if( !p.first->second ) { // handle nullptr }
}
auto &ptr = p.first->second;
```

Comment: What if there is no default constructor for `T`?

Comment: @MaxLanghof We are not constructing `T` you are constructing `shared_ptr<T>`, which always has a default constructor.

Comment: Thanks, @Slava! I'd been hoping for a slightly more ergonomic way, but I like that this requires only one lookup. I'd previously been thinking of using `.find` and then inserting if it wasn't there, but this takes into account that, by the end of the function, there should be a pointer there anyways. Works for me, though I do wish they'd considered this when writing `try_emplace`.

Comment: `.find()` would require 2 lookups so I would not recommend that, you can use `insert` `emplace` etc with default constructed `std::shared_ptr` and override `iter->second` in case insertion was successful, but it would do the same with longer code.

Comment: @Slava You actually could likely match performance with try_emplace by passing nullptr as the second argument. You'd still have to check if insertion happened and then call std::make_shared to construct the value, but you wouldn't unnecessarily construct the shared_ptr if insertion did not take place.

Comment: @ZarkBardoo right, that exactly what I said in comment before.

Comment: @Slava Unless I'm missing part of your comment, there's a slight discrepancy between emplace'ing a default constructed shared_ptr rand try_emplace'ing a nullptr—the latter never touches the constructor of shared_ptr if insertion doesn't take place (not that it's a particular expensive default constructor, but still).

Comment: @Slava: BTW, if `nullptr` is a valid value in the map (I mean if `map.at(key) == nullptr`), you overwrite it instead of keeping it.

Comment: @Jarod42 right, but if I understand OP correctly he does not want to have `nullptr`'s there. Anyway updated answer for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

Write a factory function wrapper:

```
template<class F>
struct auto_factory_t {
  F f;
  operator decltype(std::declval<F&&>()()) && {
    return std::move(f)();
  }
};
template<class F>
auto_factory_t<std::decay_t<F>> wrap_factory(F&&f){
  return {std::forward<F>(f)};
}
```

then

```
myMap.try_emplace(myString, wrap_factory([&]{return std::make_shared<T>(myString);})).first->second;
```

and done.

`wrap_factory(f)` returns an object containing `f`.  It can be implicitly cast into the type `f()` returns, and when done so calls `f()`.

Comment: Works great for a shared_ptr. Would this be more expensive for a type that's more expensive to move construct? Or is the return value of wrap_factory likely/guaranteed to be constructed in place in the map? Technically the values don't get passed all the way to an in-place construction, since the cast operator returns the factory result type directly.

Comment: @zark in C++17 no moves occur; before that, it is a candidate for elision.  So any recent compiler will not run any move ctor here, unless you force it to.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to wrap the shared pointer in your own type.  Then you can provide a constructor that takes a `T` and makes a `shared_ptr<T>`.  This lets you use `try_emplace` and pass to it a `T` without having to have anything actually created if the object already exists.  There is a lot of boiler plate involved in this though if you want to use the object as if it were a `shared_ptr<T>`.

Comment: This requires always constructing a `T` though, which the asker seems to be trying to avoid...

Comment: @MaxLanghof No it doesn't because the custom type wouldn't be constructed in cases where it already exists.

Comment: @MaxLanghof How so?  `try_emaplce` won't construct the wrapper unless it doesn't exist.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood who `T` is passed to in the third sentence ("it" being `try_emplace`, not "the constructor"). I should go home.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I updated that sentence if that helps :)

Comment: I think you need to go one step further for @RiverTam, and create a constructor for which takes string; or more generically initialiser-list; and constructs shared_ptr<T>, perhaps using make_shared?

Answer (score 2):

What you may do:

```
// C++17, else you have to move declaration outside of the `if`
// and retrieve it/inserted from pair result.
if (auto [it, inserted] = myMap.try_emplace(myString, nullptr); inserted) {
    it->second = std::make_shared<T>(myString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Modern C++17 approach**

```
template <class factory>
class deferred_factory {
public:
    deferred_factory(factory&& mfactory) : mFactory{std::move(mfactory)} {}

    // Wrap invocation of @c mFactory in an appropriate conversion operator.
    /* implicit */ operator std::invoke_result_t<factory>() {
        return mFactory();
    }

private:
    factory mFactory;
};

// Deduction guide for lvalue reference factories.
template <class factory>
deferred_factory(const factory&) -> deferred_factory<const factory&>;
```

**Explanations**

The basic trick is delaying initialization, i.e. invoking the `factory`. This is done by initializing the value type from another type (`deferred_factory`) which is implicitly convertible to the desired value type.

The conversion operator returns *exactly* the same type as invoking the `factory` directly. Due to [mandatory copy/move elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) with C++17, this imposes no extra copies whatsoever (no further `&&` / `std::move` required).

With [class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction), no further helpers for creating `deferred_factory`s are necessary. The final [deduction guide](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) allows reusing existing factories for multiple `deferred_factory`s which only wrap a *reference* to the original factory.

**Usage**

In OP's context

```
myMap.try_emplace("key", deferred_factory{[]{return std::make_shared<T>("value");}});
```

inserts "key" into `myMap` if and only if it hasn't been present before. The `shared_ptr<T>` is only ever created upon insertion.

---

This answer is a modern variant of [Yakk - Adam Nevraumont](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50933704/2747160)'s. All credit to him.