# Why isn't there a lazy version of `map::insert_or_assign`?

Tags: c++, stl

`map::insert_or_assign` seems like it was designed for implementing caches. But it's essentially useless if the value constructor is relatively expensive and the cache miss rate is approximately zero.

Is there a way to use this function in a lazy way to avoid constructing a value that's not going to be used?

Comment: Also, `insert_or_assign` was added to avoid having to do a double lookup.  If your value type is not default constructable then then you can't use `operator []` so you first have to check if the element exists and then if it does do an assignment and if not do an insertion.  `insert_or_assign` handles all of that workflow for you.

Comment: With `insert_or_assign` the value will always be used - either to construct the object or to assign to existing one. If you are looking for a way to faster insert a potentially existing object then you should check `emplace_hint`. It will require two calls instead of just one but no extra lookups or extra objects created.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for `try_emplace`, which doesn't do anything if the element is already present?

Comment: I don't understand why the value is not going to be used.

Comment: @Eljay if the key is already in the map.

Comment: Wouldn't that be more of a **insert or ignore** than **insert or assign**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to use this function in a lazy way to avoid constructing a value that's not going to be used?

The value passed to [`insert_or_assign`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert_or_assign) is *always* used:

> - If a key equivalent to `k` already exists in the container, assigns `std::forward<M>(obj)` to the `mapped_type` corresponding to the key `k`.

> - If the key does not exist, inserts the new value as if by insert, constructing it from `value_type(k, std::forward<M>(obj))`

The method you're looking for is [`try_emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/try_emplace), which will lazily construct an entry from its arguments only if the key is not already present.

Comment: i looked at try_emplace, but I couldn't work out how to lazily construct a shared_ptr as a value.

Comment: looks like this is what i need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50931315/using-try-emplace-with-a-shared-ptr